# Private template method address for default argument compiles fine with GCC but not with Clang

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, access-modifiers

This code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


int func3() { return 3; }

struct Test {
    template <typename F = std::function<int (void)>> Test(F &&f = func<int>) : _f(std::forward<F>(f)) {}  // Compile only with GCC
    //template <typename F = std::function<int (void)>> Test(F &&f = func2) : _f(std::forward<F>(f)) {}  // Compile with both
    //Test (std::function<int (void)> f = func<int>) : _f(f) {} // Compile with both

    int get() const { return _f(); }

private:
    template <typename T> static T func() { return 1; }
    static int func2() { return 2; }

    std::function<int (void)> _f;
};

int main() {
    Test t1, t2(func3);


    std::cout << t1.get() << ", " << t2.get() << std::endl;
}
```

compiles fine with GCC but not with Clang ('func' is a private member of 'Test' error).

Is this a bug of Clang ?

Comment: @W.F. In this case, it would not compile also when non-template function is used

Comment: @md5i Yes it's the same problem, do you know if the bug was reported to clang ?

Comment: @Johnmph Sorry, I do not.